# ¿Cómo elimino el último elemento de un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Debo realizar una función:

```
print(Organizar(“Enero,4,3,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4-Daniel”))
```

que me imprima lo siguiente:

```
['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}]
```

La realicé, pero al ejecutarla me imprime esto:

```
['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15, 'Daniel': 0}]
```

Este es mi código:

```
def Organizar(n):
    import re
    registros=re.split(";|-",n)
    registrosProm={}
    n=len(registros)
    

    for i in  range(n):
        lista=registros[i].split(",")
        suma=0
        for j in range(1,len(lista)):
            suma=suma+int(lista[j])
        registrosProm[lista[0]]=suma
    tupla=[lista[-1],registrosProm]
    return(tupla)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reacomodé un poco el código, con lo que automáticamente desaparece el problema:

```
def Organizar(n):
    import re
    registrosProm = {}

    for registro in re.split(";|-", n):
        lista = registro.split(",")
        if len(lista) > 1:
           registrosProm[lista[0]] = sum(map(int, lista[1:]]))

    return [registro, registrosProm]

print(Organizar("Enero,4,3,4;Febrero,4,3;Marzo,4,3,4;Abril,4,3,4,4-Daniel"))
```

produce:

```
['Daniel', {'Enero': 11, 'Febrero': 7, 'Marzo': 11, 'Abril': 15}]
```

---

*Nota*: Esta sección no la escribió Candid Moe, el me propuso que editara esta respuesta para agregar una explicación de lo que hace map, además de hacer un pequeño cambio en el código que reacomodó.

La función built-in `map` acepta dos argumentos: la función que se aplicará a cada item del iterable y el *iterable* (lista, tupla, cadena, etc). Dicha función devuelve un *iterador*.

Un iterador es un objeto el cual es aceptado como único argumento de la función `next`. Cuando la función `next` es aplicada en el iterador, se obtiene el siguiente ítem al ultimo obtenido.

Ejemplo de iterador:

```
# "123" es el iterable. Un iterable es un objeto que puede ser transformado en un iterador.
iterable = iter("123")
print(next(iterable)) => 1
print(next(iterable)) => 2
```

Ejemplo de map:

```
m = map(int, ["1","2","3"])

item1 = next(m)
print(item1, type(item1)) => 1 <class 'int'>

item2 = next(m)
print(item2, type(item2)) => 2 <class 'int'>

item3 = next(m)
print(item3, type(item3)) => 3 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: Este código `sum([int(x) for x in lista[1:]])` puede ser cambiado por `sum(map(int, lista[1:]))`. Además, al ser un iterable, evitas recorrer la lista dos veces.

Comment: Ahí lo edité c: Puedes hacerle los retoques que quieras.

Comment: @DanteS. Agregue el resultado de los ejemplos para mayor claridad.